# Assign array of datetime type into panda dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have these arrays to assign into a pandata frame.

```
date_quote = []
price1 = []
price2 = []
```

The arrays have been filled with values. `price1[]`, `price2[]` contains floating  values while `date_quote[]` contains `datetype` values.

This is how I assign the arrays into the panda dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price1 ':price1 ,
                   'price2 ': price2 ,
                   'date': date_quote
                   })
```

I get the following error;

```
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 492, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 537, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 178, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 387, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_datetime_to_tsobject
AttributeError: 'pywintypes.datetime' object has no attribute 'nanosecond'
```

The problem comes from assigning `date_quote[]` which is `datetime` type. The code runs successfully if I do not assign `date_quote[]` into the dataframe.

Contents of `date_quote[1]` looks like `2018-07-26 00:00:00+00:00`. I only need the date and do not need the time information in `date_quote[]`. Do I need to do any extra conversion to store this `datetime` type `date_quote[]` array into the dataframe?

The output of `print (date_quote[:3])` is

`[pywintypes.datetime(2018, 7, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True)), pywintypes.datetime(2018, 7, 27, 0, 0, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True)), pywintypes.datetime(2018, 7, 30, 0, 0, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True))]`

I am using python v3.6

Comment: Are you sure this is code, giving you the error? All your lists are empty!

Comment: @harvpan, the arrays have been filled with values.

Comment: How working `df = pd.DataFrame({'price1 ':price1 ,
                   'price2 ': price2 ,
                   'date': pd.to_datetime(date_quote,utc=True)
                   })` ?

Comment: Or `df = pd.DataFrame({'price1 ':price1 ,
                   'price2 ': price2 ,
                   'date': pd.to_datetime(date_quote).tz_localize('UTC')
                   })` ?

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for the tip. I still get the same error.

Comment: OK, what is `print (date_quote[:3])` ?

Comment: Output of `print (date_quote[:3])` is 
`[pywintypes.datetime(2018, 7, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True)), pywintypes.datetime(2018, 7, 27, 0, 0, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True)), pywintypes.datetime(2018, 7, 30, 0, 0, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True))]`

Comment: Do you think this error `AttributeError: 'pywintypes.datetime' object has no attribute 'nanosecond'` explains the cause? Do I have to take out the nano portion of the `date_quote`? An example of the contents is `2018-07-26 00:00:00+00:00`

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?!  This is (from my research) a fairly esoteric issue, but it applies broadly to anyone with this error.  It's answerable and it's [the only useful thing I've found.](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. The key lies in removing the time information from `date_quote[]`, leaving behind only the date information.

```
for x in range(0,int(num_elements)):
    date_quote[x] = date_quote[x].date()
```

The assignment works without error after the time information is removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `dateutil` module to extract the date and time from the string representation of the pywintypes.datetime object. This way you can keep the time part too. Code below tested with Python 3.6.

```
import datetime, dateutil, pywintypes
today = datetime.datetime.now()  # get today's date as an example
mypydate = pywintypes.Time(today)  # create a demo pywintypes object
mydate = dateutil.parser.parse(str(mypydate))  # convert it to a python datetime
print(mydate)
print(type(mydate))
```

Output:

```
2019-05-11 12:44:03.320533
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```